# Laravel rule integer prevent overflow

Tags: php, laravel, api

Do I need to create a rule, which checks if an integer doesn't overflow, or is this case already intercepted by the API (e.g. in 32 Bit Systems, do I need to add the rule: `min:-2147483648|max:2147483647`)?

Comment: It looks like you should, otherwise you should just limit it to the one your model/business requires.

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary. The `int` validation rule will not pass for overflowing and underflowing integers it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short test revealed as @apokryfos already stated, that you **don't** to need to check for the lower and upper **bounds** of an integer.

But when you want to limit your integer to a specific size (e. g. 32 Bit), then you need to provide the bounds limit.

In my test run, the size of an integer was 64 Bit.